# Pagination without using database in PHP

Tags: php, glob

I am trying to create a webpage which shows 10 files stored in a directory each time. I don't want to use database for it though. This is what I have up to this point.

```
<?php 
$exclude = array("index.php");
$cssfiles = array_diff(glob("*.php"), $exclude); 
foreach ($cssfiles as $cssfile) {
$filename = "http://example.com/lessons/css/".$cssfile;
outputtags($filename,true,true); 
}
?>
```

This prints out all results, I can't figure out how to show just first ten results and after that when user clicks next 10 more results without using database. I think using a database just for this purpose doesn't make sense.

**EDIT** The reason I want to do it this way is because I am getting max_user_connection error.

Comment: Because files have no real order in a directory you can never guarantee getting the next 10 unless you perform a sort. Build an array of all of the file names that you can use for sorting and pagination.

Comment: *"I don't want to use database for it though."* - Why not? It's a lot less trouble and maintenance using a DB.

Comment: I got some error like max_connection something

Comment: That's a nice error there @SheelRanjan. Is that why you don't want to use a database?

Comment: fixing max_connections is probably a good thing anyway. However, you can just create an sqlite database and read it as if it is just a simple file

Comment: Yes @JayBlanchard this is the reason The exact name of error is **max_user_connection** I am on a shared host which allows 10 user_connections. I don't exactly know what this means but  this error started appearing today.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by storing your files into an array and sort it as you wish, like following :

```
    $exclude = array("index.php");
    $cssfiles = array_diff(glob("*.php"), $exclude); 
    $files = array();
    foreach ($cssfiles as $cssfile) {
    $filename = "http://example.com/lessons/css/".$cssfile;
       $files[] = $filename;
    }

    asort($files);

    // Pagination start from here
    $page = 1; // You will get this parameter from the url using $_GET['page'] for instance
    $limit  = 10; // Number of files to display.
    $offset = (($page-1) * $limit);
    $max = ($page * $limit);
    $max = $max > count($files)  ? count($files) : $max;

    for ($i=$offset; $i<$max; $i++) {
        echo $files[$i] . PHP_EOL;
    }

    echo 'Total Pages : ', count($files). PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Page number : ' , $page;
```

Maybe you could use ajax and extract the pagination page to avoid fetching all the files each time.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how you want to select those ten pages. One could use a `for` loop that lists the files 0-9 as and may count from 10-19,..., depening on the page range the user requests.

However, when a file is added, the system would get out of order. In that case, loading / saving some sorting Information to sessions / cookies could solve the problem.

EDIT : Using a database is, however, the standard for tasks like this. Even if you don't like them, you will most likely need them for more complex Tasks that require sorting, searching or joining multiple datasets, that are just too complicated to achieve with the filesystem functions.